# Bootstrap Grid shifts when validation DIV visible

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the below form that uses Bootstrap.

Everything seems to be working fine, until some of the fields have validation errors. When that happens, I make the feedback DIVs visible, which shifts the grid alignment.

I'm not sure what's causing this as my column sizes add up to under 12 per form-row, so they shouldn't be shifting to the next row. Any ideas would be great.

Thanks in advance.

**Normal Layout**
[image]

**Shifted Layout** (when there are validation errors)
[image]

**Markup**

```
<div class="account-options account-options-banking-details row" id="divBankingDetails" runat="server">
    <hr />
    <h1>Banking Details</h1>
    <div class="account-options-banking-controls col-xs-10">
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-xs-5">
                <label for="txtBankName">Bank Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control inputfield" id="txtBankName" runat="server">
                <div class="invalid-feedback" id="divBankNameFeedback" runat="server" visible="false">
                    Required
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-xs-5">
                <label for="txtAccountType">Account Type</label>
                <select class="form-control inputfield custom-select" ID="cboAccountType" runat="server">
                    <option Value="0">Choose...</option>
                    <option Value="1">Checking</option>
                    <option Value="2">Savings</option>
                </select>
                <div class="invalid-feedback" id="divAccountTypeFeedback" runat="server" visible="false">
                    Required
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-xs-5">
                <label for="txtBankAccountNumber">Bank Account Number</label>
                <input class="form-control inputfield acct-number" name="BankAccountNumber" id="txtBankAccountNumber" runat="server">
                <span toggle=".acct-number" class="fa fa-fw fa-eye field-icon toggle-account-number"></span>
                <div class="invalid-feedback" id="divBankAccountNumberFeedback" runat="server" visible="false">
                    Required
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-xs-5">
                <label for="txtReenterBankAccountNumber">Re-enter Bank Account Number</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control inputfield" id="txtReenterBankAccountNumber" runat="server">
                <div class="invalid-feedback" id="divReenterBankAccountNumberFeedback" runat="server" visible="false">
                    Required
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-xs-5">
                <label for="txtRoutingNumber">Routing Number</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control inputfield" id="txtRoutingNumber" runat="server">
                <div class="invalid-feedback" id="divRoutingNumberFeedback" runat="server" visible="false">
                    Required
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `.row` instead of `.form-row`. `.form-row` is for Bootstrap 4